# How to solve error Expected singleton: purchase.order.line (57, 58, 59, 60, 61, 62, 63, 64)

Tags: python-2.7, odoo-9

I'm using odoo version 9 and I've created a module to customize the reports of purchase order. Among the fields that I want displayed in the reports is the supplier reference for article but when I add the code that displays this field  `<span> <t t-esc="', '.join([str(x.product_code) for x in o.order_line.product_id.product_tmpl_id.seller_ids])"/>`
  but it displays an error when I want to start printing the report
`QWebException: "Expected singleton: purchase.order.line(57, 58, 59, 60, 61, 62, 63, 64)" while evaluating
"', '.join([str(x.product_code) for x in o.order_line.product_id.product_tmpl_id.seller_ids])"`

PS: I don't change anything in the module purchase. 
I don't know how to fix this problem any idea for help please ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It is because your purchase order got several orderlines and you are hoping that the order will have only one orderline.

o.orderline.product_id.product_tmpl_id.seller_ids

will work only if there is one orderline otherwise you have loop through each orderline. Here o.orderline will have multiple orderlines and you can get product_id from multiple orderline. If you try o.orderline[0].product_id.product_tmpl_id.seller_ids it will work but will get only first orderline details. Inorder to get all the orderline details you need to loop through it.

Answer (score 1):

There are more than one seller ids found . That's why you are getting number of ids here .i.e. purchase.order.line(57, 58, 59, 60, 61, 62, 63, 64). You have to select one of the id among them . To see the result just try this :

```
o.order_line[0].product_id.product_tmpl_id.seller_ids
```

If you want to show all of these seller ids on report apply for loop in to the xml.

Comment: could you describe with the code you have written in python as well as in xml for this particular problem?